# Can we have Two android sdk folders in our computer

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have installed eclipse with one android sdk in C drive. I have mentioned this android sdk-tools in environment variables.
Recently I have installed android studio with another sdk in D drive. Do I need to specify this sdk-tools in environment variable??

Comment: AFAIK, no, there's no need to do this. Android Studio uses some projects' files to see where the SDK is located.

Comment: You can have both Eclipse and Android Studio refer to the same Android SDK folder. There's no point having both, you will only be duplicating SDK files.

Comment: What about android sdk for Xamarin and sdk for android studio? Can I have same sdk for both platform?